# Why won't my mob farm work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have built a mob farm in my single player world, but it doesn't work.

I have tested the mob farm in a super flat world and it works well. I have built them almost identical, the only difference is that I used snow blocks instead of cobble and that half my mob farm is built in a deep ocean biome and the other half is in an ocean biome. I have checked and there is no light in the farm and no caves under it. I have searched for an asnwer but nothing seems to work.

I copied the farm from logdotzips 34th episode of how to minecraft.

Comment: You say they're identical _except_ X and Y are different. Try making them identical and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks. If tried but I beleive the design isn't working.

Comment: If you suspect there is a problem in the design, it would be _very_ helpful to include references to that design; say with pictures from minecraft or similar. If you got the design from a website, it may be useful to include that as well. In the meantime, after you do this and while you wait for answers, you may find some very useful information here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn#Spawn_cycle ; especially under 'Spawn conditions'

Comment: I copied the farm from logdotzips 34th episode of how to minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**
The problem that you had is because of the cave underground / near the mob farm. Why superflat world worked? Simply because there is no cave under / below it.

**Why?**
Why is it? It's because when a mob want to spawn, the game simply search for a random location with certain requirement needed. In this situation is Light Level.

**How to fix it**
Well simply enough, you must make the light level of near by caves up. You can see the block you're standing light level by entering the Debug Menu by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>. Make sure there is no near by cave to have light level of 7 or below. Make sure also there is no cave with light level 7 or below in 64 block from the middle of the farm.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest using the Monster Cobble. I usually play on creative and theres a stone that spawns monsters.

You could try building it out of that?